# split a list using list to get smaller lists

Tags: python, list

how can I split a list using a predefined list, I want to split list `x` into multiple smaller lists (or dictionaries) when an element from the list `titles` is found

```
titles=['a','c','g','final']

x=['a',3,4,2,'c','b','b1',2,'g','final',...]
```

expected output

```
new_list=[['a',3,4,2],['c','b','b1',2],['g'],['final',...]]
# OR
my_dict={'a':[3,4,2],'c':['b','b1',2],'g':[],'final':[...]}
```

Note: elements in titles are unique in x (i.e 'a' will not be found more than once in `x`)

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can compute the indexes of each title:

   ```
   indexes = list(map(x.index, titles))
   # or indexes = [x.index(title) for title in titles]
   ```
2. Then `zip` `indexes` with `indexes[1:]` this will make pairs of each index with the next one:

   ```
   z = zip(indexes, indexes[1:] + [None])
   print(list(z))  # [(0, 4), (4, 8), (8, 9), (9, None)]
   ```
3. Then use it to split:

   - To get the list of sublists:

     ```
     resultlist = [x[fr:to] for fr, to in zip(indexes, indexes[1:] + [None])]
     # [['a', 3, 4, 2], ['c', 'b', 'b1', 2], ['g'], ['final', 'value']]
     ```
   - To get the dict:

     ```
     resultdict = {x[fr]: x[fr + 1:to] for fr, to in zip(indexes, indexes[1:] + [None])}
     # {'a': [3, 4, 2], 'c': ['b', 'b1', 2], 'g': [], 'final': ['value']}
     ```

Answer (score 0):

with support of duplications in `titles`

```
titles = ['a', 'c', 'g', 'final']

x = ['a', 3, 4, 2, 'c', 'b', 'b1', 2, 'g', 'final', 'r', 'gg']
new_list = []
starting_index = 0
for i in range(0, len(titles) - 1):
    f = x.index(titles[i], starting_index)
    t = x.index(titles[i + 1], starting_index)
    sub_list = x[f:t]
    new_list.append(sub_list)
    starting_index = t

l = x.index(titles[-1])
last_sub_list = x[l:]
new_list.append(last_sub_list)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: This works, but I believe there is a more "pythonic" way (coming from C background)

Answer (score 0):

```
titles=['a','c','g','final']
x=['a',3,4,2,'c','b','b1',2,'g','final','r', 'gg']

result = []

for idx, val in enumerate(x):
    if val in titles:
        sublist = [val]
        i = idx+1
        while (i < len(x) and x[i] not in titles):
            sublist.append(x[i])
            i += 1
        result.append(sublist)
    idx += (i-idx)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this would be:

```
titles = ["a", "c", "g", "final"]
x = ["a", 3, 4, 2, "c", "b", "b1", 2, "g", "final", "x", "y", "z"]

result = [
    x[x.index(i) : j and x.index(j)]
    for i, j in zip(titles, titles[1:] + [None])
]
```

or

```
result = [
    x[x.index(i) : x.index(j) if j else None]
    for i, j in zip(titles, titles[1:] + [None])
]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 3, 4, 2], ['c', 'b', 'b1', 2], ['g'], ['final', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
```

To get a dictionary:

```
result = {
    x[x.index(i)]: x[x.index(i) : j and x.index(j)]
    for i, j in zip(titles, titles[1:] + [None])
}
```

or

```
result = {
    x[x.index(i)]: x[x.index(i) + 1 : x.index(j) if j else None]
    for i, j in zip(titles, titles[1:] + [None])
}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [3, 4, 2], 'c': ['b', 'b1', 2], 'g': [], 'final': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
```